# Need explanations for Linux bash builtin exec command behavior

Tags: bash, exec

From [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-exec) I get the following about `exec` bash builtin command:

> If command is supplied, it replaces the shell without creating a new process.

Now I have the following `bash` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exec ls;
echo 123;
exit 0
```

This executed, I got this (files from the current directory):

```
cleanup.sh  ex1.bash  file.bash  file.bash~  output.log
```

Now, if I have this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exec ls | cat
echo 123
exit 0
```

I get the following output:

```
cleanup.sh
ex1.bash
file.bash
file.bash~
output.log
123
```

My question is:

If when `exec` is invoked *it replaces the shell without creating a new process*, why when put `| cat`, the `echo 123` is printed, but without it, it isn't. So, I would be happy if someone can explain what's the logic of this behavior.

Thanks.

EDIT:
After @torek response, I get an even harder to explain behavior:

1.`exec ls>out` command creates the `out` file and put in it the `ls`'s command result;

2.`exec ls>out1 ls>out2` creates only the files, but do not put inside any result. If the command works as suggested, I think the command number 2 should have the same result as command number 1 (even more, I think it should not have had created the `out2` file).

Comment: You link on `exec` is the C `exec` function. What you are testing is the `bash` `exec` buildin. They are not the same. See www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html

Comment: @J-16SDiZ corrected as you suggested, but the issue persists

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In this particular case, you have the `exec` in a pipeline.  In order to execute a series of pipeline commands, the shell must initially fork, making a sub-shell.  (Specifically it has to create the pipe, then fork, so that everything run "on the left" of the pipe can have its output sent to whatever is "on the right" of the pipe.)

To see that this is in fact what is happening, compare:

```
{ ls; echo this too; } | cat
```

with:

```
{ exec ls; echo this too; } | cat
```

The former runs `ls` without leaving the sub-shell, so that this sub-shell is therefore still around to run the `echo`.  The latter runs `ls` by leaving the sub-shell, which is therefore no longer there to do the `echo`, and `this too` is not printed.

(The use of curly-braces `{ cmd1; cmd2; }` normally suppresses the sub-shell fork action that you get with parentheses `(cmd1; cmd2)`, but in the case of a pipe, the fork is "forced", as it were.)

Redirection of the current shell happens only if there is "nothing to run", as it were, after the word `exec`.  Thus, e.g., `exec >stdout 4<input 5>>append` modifies the current shell, but `exec foo >stdout 4<input 5>>append` tries to exec command `foo`. [Note: this is not strictly accurate; see addendum.]

Interestingly, in an interactive shell, after `exec foo >output` fails because there is no command `foo`, the shell sticks around, but stdout remains redirected to file `output`.  (You can recover with `exec >/dev/tty`.  In a script, the failure to `exec foo` terminates the script.)

---

With a tip of the hat to @Pumbaa80, here's something even more illustrative:

```
#! /bin/bash
shopt -s execfail
exec ls | cat -E
echo this goes to stdout
echo this goes to stderr 1>&2
```

(note: `cat -E` is simplified down from my usual `cat -vET`, which is my handy go-to for "let me see non-printing characters in a recognizable way").  When this script is run, the output from `ls` has `cat -E` applied (on Linux this makes end-of-line visible as a $ sign), but the output sent to stdout and stderr (on the remaining two lines) is *not* redirected.  Change the `| cat -E` to `> out` and, after the script runs, observe the contents of file `out`: the final two `echo`s are not in there.

Now change the `ls` to `foo` (or some other command that will not be found) and run the script again.  This time the output is:

```
$ ./demo.sh
./demo.sh: line 3: exec: foo: not found
this goes to stderr
```

and the file `out` now has the contents produced by the first `echo` line.

This makes what `exec` "really does" as obvious as possible (but no more obvious, as Albert Einstein did not put it :-) ).

Normally, when the shell goes to execute a "simple command" (see the manual page for the precise definition, but this specifically excludes the commands in a "pipeline"), it prepares any I/O redirection operations specified with `<`, `>`, and so on by opening the files needed.  Then the shell invokes `fork` (or some equivalent but more-efficient variant like `vfork` or `clone` depending on underlying OS, configuration, etc), and, in the child process, rearranges the open file descriptors (using `dup2` calls or equivalent) to achieve the desired final arrangements: `> out` moves the open descriptor to fd 1—stdout—while `6> out` moves the open descriptor to fd 6.

If you specify the `exec` keyword, though, the shell suppresses the `fork` step.  It does all the file opening and file-descriptor-rearranging as usual, but this time, *it affects any and all subsequent commands*.  Finally, having done all the redirections, the shell attempts to `execve()` (in the system-call sense) the command, if there is one.  If there is no command, or if the `execve()` call fails *and* the shell is supposed to continue running (is interactive or you have set `execfail`), the shell soldiers on.  If the `execve()` succeeds, the shell no longer exists, having been replaced by the new command.  If `execfail` is unset and the shell is not interactive, the shell exits.

(There's also the added complication of the `command_not_found_handle` shell function: bash's `exec` seems to suppress running it, based on test results.  The `exec` keyword in general makes the shell not look at its own functions, i.e., if you have a shell function f, running `f` as a simple command runs the shell function, as does `(f)` which runs it in a sub-shell, but running `(exec f)` skips over it.)

---

As for why `ls>out1 ls>out2` creates two files (with or without an `exec`), this is simple enough: the shell opens each redirection, and then uses `dup2` to move the file descriptors.  If you have two ordinary `>` redirects, the shell opens both, moves the first one to fd 1 (stdout), then moves the second one to fd 1 (stdout again), closing the first in the process.  Finally, it runs `ls ls`, because that's what's left after removing the `>out1 >out2`.  As long as there is no file named `ls`, the `ls` command complains to stderr, and writes nothing to stdout.

Comment: As for the (non-)interactive shell, the manpage says " If `command` cannot be executed  for  some  reason, a non-interactive shell exits, unless the shell option `execfail` is enabled, in which case it returns failure. An interactive shell returns failure"

Comment: @torek look at the EDIT part in the question

Comment: @Pumbaa80: very nice; this helps make "how exec works" clearer.  I'll add a note to my answer.