# I don't understand bash exec

Tags: bash, exec

```
#!/bin/bash
#...
exec >> logfile
#cmd
```

I guest it's save output.
Could you expand it with the same example?
Thank you very much!

I often use this command to list txt files:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l "bash" {} \;
```

but I can't very understand too.

---

How can there be such good people in the world.very very moved!

Comment: Please refine your question. Currently, it's too broad and difficult to understand

Comment: `>>` allow you to add output of something to the end of the file. Currently "exec" result will be added to the end of logfile.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920512/need-explanations-for-linux-bash-builtin-exec-command-behavior

Comment: Thanks Sergio Ivanuzzo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it sends any further output to the file named `logfile`.  In other words, it redirects *standard output* (also known as *stdout*) to the file `logfile`.

#### Example

Let's start with this script:

```
$ cat >script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo First
exec >>logfile
echo Second
```

If we run the script, we see output from the first but not the second `echo` statements:

```
$ bash script.sh
First
```

The output from the second `echo` statement went to the file `logfile`:

```
$ cat logfile
Second
$
```

If we had used `exec >logfile`, then the `logfile` would be *overwritten* each time the script was run.  Because we used `>>` instead of `>`, however, the output will be *appended* to `logfile`.  For example, if we run it once again:

```
$ bash script.sh
First
$ cat logfile
Second
Second
```

#### Documentation

This is documented in `man bash`:

> **exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]**
>  If command
>   is specified, it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The
>   arguments become the arguments to command.  If the -l option is
>   supplied, the shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth
>   argument passed to command.  This is what login(1) does.  The -c
>   option causes command to be executed with an empty environment.   If 
>   -a is  supplied, the shell passes name as the zeroth argument to the executed command.  If command cannot be executed for some reason, a
>   non-interactive shell exits, unless the execfail shell option is
>   enabled.  In that case, it returns failure.  An interactive shell
>   returns failure if the file cannot be executed.  **If command is not
>   specified,  any redirections take effect in the current shell, and the
>   return status is 0.**  If there is a redirection error, the return
>   status is 1. [Emphasis added.]

In your case, no *command* argument is specified. So, the `exec` command performs redirections which, in this case, means any further stdout is sent to file `logfile`.

### find command and -exec

The find command has a `-exec` option.  For example:

```
find / -type f -exec grep -l "bash" {} \;
```

Other than the similarity in name, the `-exec` here has absolutely nothing to do with the shell command `exec`.

The construct `-exec grep -l "bash" {} \;` tells `find` to *execute* the command `grep -l "bash"` on any files that it finds.  This is unrelated to the shell command `exec >>logfile` which executes nothing but has the effect of redirecting output.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you output to stdout will not go to stdout but to the logfile.
See example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# reassign-stdout.sh

LOGFILE=logfile.txt

exec 6>&1           # Link file descriptor #6 with stdout.
                    # Saves stdout.

exec > $LOGFILE     # stdout replaced with file "logfile.txt".

# ----------------------------------------------------------- #
# All output from commands in this block sent to file $LOGFILE.

echo -n "Logfile: "
date
echo "-------------------------------------"
echo

echo "Output of \"ls -al\" command"
echo
ls -al
echo; echo
echo "Output of \"df\" command"
echo
df

# ----------------------------------------------------------- #

exec 1>&6 6>&-      # Restore stdout and close file descriptor #6.

echo
echo "== stdout now restored to default == "
echo
ls -al
echo

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This redirects standard output produced by your script and any other programs it subsequently calls into the `logfile`. So if your script runs in terminal after it executes

```
exec >> logfile
```

you'll see no output in your terminal window but you'll find it inside the `logfile`. `logfile` will be created if it doesn't exist or appended every time you run your script.