# What does set -e and exec "$@" do for docker entrypoint scripts?

Tags: shell, docker

I've noticed that many entrypoint.sh scripts for docker do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

... code ...

exec "$@"
```

What are the `set -e` and the `exec "$@"` for?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) re: why `set -e` is considered far more error-prone than hand-written error handling. (If in a hurry, skip the analogy at the top for the exercises below).

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It basically takes any command line arguments passed to `entrypoint.sh` and execs them as a command. The intention is basically "Do everything in this .sh script, then in the same shell run the command the user passes in on the command line".

See:

- [What are the special dollar sign shell variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)
- [Need explanations for Linux bash builtin exec command behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920512/need-explanations-for-linux-bash-builtin-exec-command-behavior)

Comment: Note also that `exec "$@"` will replace the currently running process with the new process spawned for the passed arguments. Important for Docker signaling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261019/99717

Comment: But there is a difference between `exec $@` and `exex "$@"` (quoted version). Former allows globbing. So that `docker run ... ls /*` should work better. But at the same time break arguments having spaces in them...

Answer (score 75):

`set -e` sets a shell option to immediately exit if any command being run exits with a non-zero exit code. The script will return with the exit code of the failing command. From the bash man page:

> set -e:
>
> Exit  immediately  if  a  pipeline (which may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL
>   GRAMMAR above), exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does not exit
>   if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately
>   following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if
>   or elif reserved words, part of any command executed in a && or ||
>   list except the  command  following  the  final  &&  or ||, any
>   command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command's return value
>   is being inverted with !.  If a compound command other than a subshell
>   returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e was being
>   ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is executed
>   before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell environment
>   and each  subshell  environment separately (see COMMAND EXECUTION
>   ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before executing
>   all the commands in the subshell.
>
> If  a  compound command or shell function executes in a context where
>   -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if
>   -e is set and a command returns a failure status.  If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where
>   -e is ignored, that setting will not have any  effect  until  the  compound command or the command containing the function call
>   completes.

---

`exec "$@"` is typically used to make the entrypoint a pass through that then runs the docker command. It will replace the current running shell with the command that `"$@"` is pointing to. By default, that variable points to the command line arguments.

If you have an image with an entrypoint pointing to entrypoint.sh, and you run your container as `docker run my_image server start`, that will translate to running `entrypoint.sh server start` in the container. At the exec line `entrypoint.sh`, the shell running as pid 1 will replace itself with the command `server start`.

This is critical for signal handling. Without using `exec`, the `server start` in the above example would run as another pid, and after it exits, you would return to your shell script. With a shell in pid 1, a SIGTERM will be ignored by default. That means the graceful stop signal that `docker stop` sends to your container, would never be received by the `server` process. After 10 seconds (by default), `docker stop` would give up on the graceful shutdown and send a SIGKILL that will force your app to exit, but with potential data loss or closed network connections, that app developers could have coded around if they received the signal. It also means your container will always take the 10 seconds to stop.

Note that with shell commands like `shift` and `set --`, you can change the value of `"$@"`. E.g. here's a short part of a script that removes the `/bin/sh -c "..."` from the command that can appear if you use docker's shell syntax for `CMD`:

```
# convert `/bin/sh -c "server start"` to `server start`
if [ $# -gt 1 ] && [ x"$1" = x"/bin/sh" ] && [ x"$2" = x"-c" ]; then
  shift 2
  eval "set -- $1"
fi

....

exec "$@"
```

Comment: See [the POSIX `test` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), which marks `-a` obsolescent. `[ "$#" -gt 1 ] && [ "$1" = /bin/sh ]` is the correct replacement (there's no need for the `x"$1"` hackery when using only the non-obsolete syntax).

Comment: Also, `shift 2; set -- $1` is not at all the same as how `eval` will parse the string. Consider `/bin/sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "hello world" "goodbye world"'`, if you want a concrete test case, and see [Bash doesn't parse quotes when converting a string to arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857027/bash-doesnt-parse-quotes-when-converting-a-string-to-arguments).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip on the obsolescent option, I'm sure I'll make this mistake again, old habits die hard. With the `eval`, I believe I still want that to mirror the behavior of `/bin/sh -c` would have on the string, but please let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 38):

`set -e` - exit script if any command fails (non-zero value)

`exec "$@"` - will redirect input variables, see more [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec)

Comment: "Will redirect input variables"? Eh? `exec` certainly does have a usage mode where it's performing redirections, but this isn't that mode.