# Docker How to run /usr/sbin/init and then other scripts on start up

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /data/
ENTRYPOINT ["/data/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
exec /usr/sbin/init && systemctl restart autofs %% python /data/myapp.py
```

I need to run `/usr/sbin/init` as the first command then run subsequent commands such as `systemctl restart autofs` and `python myapp.py`

I cant seem to get all working inside docker-entrypoint.sh because `/usr/sbin/init` does not return

if i change docker-entrypoint.sh to

```
/usr/sbin/init &
systemctl restart autofs && python /data/myapp.py
```

it fails with error in d-bus

what can i do so the container runs `/usr/sbin/init`, `systemctl restart autofs` and `python /data/myapp.py` in that order when "docker run" is executed?

Is there any other ways to run commands after `/usr/sbin/init` is executed?
i've tried putting systemctl as CMD in Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init"]
CMD ["systemctl restart autofs"]
```

but CMD is never executed

Comment: The error about d-bus comes from systemctl to have executed. That's because systemctl uses d-bus to talk to the systemd daemon.

May be you want to avoid the init/dbus thing with the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Declaring

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init"]
CMD ["systemctl"]
```

Will result in:

```
/usr/sbin/init systemctl
```

In other words, the `ENTRYPOINT` directive sets the executable which is used to execute the command given from the `COMMAND` directive.

The default `ENTRYPOINT` is `/bin/sh -c` so `/bin/sh -c /data/docker-entrypoint.sh` should work, if `/data/docker-entrypoint.sh` contains:

```
/usr/sbin/init
systemctl restart autofs
python /data/myapp.py
```

That means: You don't have to change the `ENTRYPOINT`

If you change the the `ENTRYPOINT` to `/data/docker-entrypoint.sh` than it should contain something like:

```
/usr/sbin/init
systemctl restart autofs
python /data/myapp.py
# run the command given as arguments from CMD
exec "$@"
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082768/what-does-set-e-and-exec-do-for-docker-entrypoint-scripts)

Comment: this worked for me, thanks

Comment: this cannot work. your shell script will have PID 1 and you need init to be PID 1.