# How to install logstash plugin with docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, logstash

I try to install logstash with a `docker-compose` but docker `exited with code 0` just after `Installation successful` when I try to install a logstash plugin.

The part of docker-compose file for logstash is:

```
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.0.1
    ports: ['9600:9600']
    command: bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-metricize
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
```

And the logs are:

```
logstash_1       |Validating logstash-filter-metricize
logstash_1       |Installing logstash-filter-metricize
logstash_1       |Installation successful
logstash_1 exited with code 0
```

If I try without install the plugin, my docker-compose works fine. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong when I install the plugin.

Comment: your logstash part is doing your command section. So its run bin/logstash-plugin install after that installation its ended (without error ). You can add this command to step as a dockerfile or you can add another command for like '$@' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082768/what-does-set-e-and-exec-do-for-docker-entrypoint-scripts

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use a Dockerfile to fix it.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:7.0.1

RUN rm -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf && \
  bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-metricize
```

My part of `docker-compose`:

```
  logstash:
    build: 
      context: ./logstash
    ports: ['9600:9600']
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to chain logstash startup command after install.

```
  command: bash -c "bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-metricize && logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf "
```